# On managed Macs, how much can the admin see?

Tags: macos, privacy, mobile-device-management, profile-manager

I have a Macbook that was given to me by my employer.

The Macbook is managed by them as I can see the installed profiles. These profiles control things like how/when to set up my password, apps that should be installed etc...

I would like to know if they have access to my computer and how much can they do/see ?

Things like, Can they see my screen? Can they see what I'm typing? Can they which applications I've installed? Can they access the contents of my drives?

If possible, provide references to official Apple documentation/sites detailing this.

Comment: The answer to all your questions is **Yes**. As somebody who maintains and sets up MDM profiles on computers and iPads for my institution, _all_ of what you are concerned about is possible, and some of these abilities are undetectable by the end user. In addition, all your web traffic is likely monitored and logged for future forensic analysis. If you are concerned about what your employer sees on your computer, use it for work tasks only. Purchase your own laptop for personal work, _and don't connect it to your employer's Wi-Fi_. Use cell service on your phone, too. You _are_ being watched.

Comment: Thank you. I need to clarify this, can they really see my screen? I check my personal email on this computer (doesn't seem like a big deal to me), but I definitely wouldn't want them to see it.

Comment: [Apple Remote Desktop](https://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/remoteassistance.html) is one such method although they could be using something else. Check your email on your _cell_ phone.

Comment: Speaking from personal experience, as an Admin I could not only see everything, I could screen capture, key log, and track virtually everything  an employee did. Did I?  Generally no unless mgmt or HR gave me a reason to do so.  That said, do all your personal stuff on your personal machine